# threads, tasks, states, need help picking the right one

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need some help in choosing the right tool. I'm replacing the hardware controller that controls some pumps with a raspberry pi and writing code for it in c# .netcore. The pumps should run in a specific sequence and for a specified duration. With all the possible ways to accomplish this, I'm looking for the cleanest and interesting one.

The pumps should do the following:

- Turn on pump 1
- wait 15 seconds
- turn on pump 2
- wait 10 minutes
- turn on pump 3
- let pump 3 run for 20 minutes
- turn off pump 3
- wait 10 minutes
- turn off pump 2
- wait 15 seconds
- turn off pump 1

I looked into timers, threads, tasks, state machine but I have a hard time picking the right tool for this job. At all times, I also need to be able to stop immediately all pumps.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My general suggestion is this. Start by writing the dumbest possible code without tasks or threads (using `Thread.Sleep` etc etc). Then, if it works - fine, use it. If it doesn't, share the code with us and detail what about it isn't working for you.

Comment: You could use Timer and queue with execution jobs.When job is executed it is placed to end of the queue. Your jobs execution will be ordered in this case and executed only one in one time.

Comment: @It'satrap `static async Task Main() {...}` <== job done

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry my knowledge was obsolete. I would delete my comment in a minute

Comment: I would go with `asnyc` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57388826/10883465) from Magnus) since you need to be able to stop starting new pumps if you decide to stop all the pumps before all are started. This would be easy to implement with a `CancellationToken` which you would pass in the `StartAll` method. Then check if you should cancel before starting a new pump. You can also pass in the `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Delay` method which is really handy (and arguably necessary) in this scenario.

Comment: Look in to RX, implementation for Observer pattern.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably go with tasks.

```
public async Task Execute()
{
    await TurnOnPump1();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    await TurnOnPump2();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    await TurnOnPump3();
    //And so on..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the [great answer from Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57388826/10883465), here's how you could implement cancellation so you could stop executing the method (stop starting new pumps) if you decide to stop all of them.

I posted this answer because OP specifically said that they need to be able to stop the pumps *at all times*, so Magnus' answer wouldn't quite work in certain scenarios.

> At all times, I also need to be able to stop immediately all pumps.

```
public async Task StartAll(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await TurnOnPump1(); // no ct here because these methods should take little to no time to execute
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), ct);
    await TurnOnPump2();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), ct);
    await TurnOnPump3();
    //And so on..
}

public asnyc Task StopAll()
{
    // Your_CancellationTokenSource should be defined somewhere else
    Your_CancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); // this line makes Task.Delay throw a TaskCanceledException
    await StopPump1();  
    await StopPump2();   
    await StopPump3();   
    // ..
}

public async Task HowToCallStart()
{
    try
    {
        // Your_CancellationTokenSource should be defined somewhere else
        await StartAll(Your_CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // Starting was canceled
    }
}
```

This way, `StopAll` can be called anytime during the starting and you don't get any issues.

A few things to mention:

- `Your_CancellationTokenSource` should of course be some variable outside of these methods so it can be shared. It needs to be of type [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource).
- As you can see by the comment (both in code and below answer), I assumed that starting a pump would be very fast and take very little to no time. That is the reason I did not pass in my `CancellationToken`.
  If turning on the pumps takes some time, consider using `CancellationToken` inside the `TurnOnPumpX` methods as well to abort if the operation was canceled. If you do so, you can simply pass in `ct` to those methods as well.
- You should add some code in the `catch` for when the operation is canceled. At least print out a debug message if the end-user doesn't need to see it.

Comment: Good addition with the how to stop the pumps. Totally missed that in the question. One observation though, there is no need to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` after `Task.Delay` when sending in a `CancellationToken` to it as it will throw itself. But it might be an idea to send it down to the `TurnOnPump` functions.

Comment: Absolutely correct. In my mind they just jumped out of delay, I completely forgot that they also throw an exception (not `OperationCanceledException` but `TaskCanceledException` though, small difference). The reason I didn't pass the `CancellationToken` to the `TurnOnPumpX` functions is because these functions are only supposed to start/turn on the pumps. This should take a very small amount of time so implementing cancellation there would probably only result in an unnecessary overhead, don't you think?

Comment: `TaskCanceledException` inherits from `OperationCanceledException` so your code would still work. As for how long the pumps takes to start, who knows :-)

Comment: Right again. I'm not as firm on Task-exceptions as I thought oops. I will add some clarifications to the answer regarding the `TurnOnPumpX` methods. Thanks for the insights.